# Remove HEX representation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write JavaScript code that removes the HEX representation of an attribute and make it a string. 
For example, I received this attribute
`000: 00 06 f2 20 29 05 b1 11` from the API I and need to convert it to `0006f2202905 b111` in a string.

How can I do that?

Comment: `string.replace(/[0-9]+: /, '').replace(/\s/g, '');`

Answer (score 0):

```
var string= "000: 00 06 f2 20 29 05 b1 11";

string = string.replace(/.*?:/g, ""); //remove 000:
string = string.replace(/\s+/g, ""); // remove spaces
alert(string)
```

---

**Output:**

```
0006f2202905b111
```

---

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/tuga/pen/vOBdYd)